Simple Linear Regression, impact of standardizing data
Let's assume we have $(X_i, Y_i), 1 \le i \le n$ a series of $n$ observations.
I want to explain $Y^T = (Y_1, \dots, Y_n)$ as a linear function of $X^T = (X_1, \dots, X_n)$. My model is:
$$
Y = \beta_0 1_n + \beta_1 X + \epsilon
$$
In the simple, univariate case, computing the hat matrix gives:
$$
\beta_1 = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y = (\sum x_i^2)^{-1}(\sum x_i y_i) = \dfrac{cov(X, Y)}{Var(X)}
$$
And:
$$
\beta_0 = \overline{X} - \beta_1 \overline{Y}
$$
Where $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$ are the sample mean, such that $\overline{X} = \dfrac{1}{n} \sum X_i$
I want to check my assumptions:

If $X$ and $Y$ are centered beforehand, the intercept $\beta_0$ will be $0$, since $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$ will both be equal to $0$. Am I right? I don't believe it generalizes to the multivariate case. Does it?

If $X$ and $Y$ are centered beforehand, I believe the slope won't change if we compute $Cov(X - \mu_X, Y - \mu_Y)$, but I am not sure, since $\mu_X, \mu_Y$ are not known (we only have access to the sample mean, as an estimator, i.e. as a random variable).


Note that in 2. the question seems to sum up to: $Cov(X - \overline{X}, Y - \overline{Y}) \stackrel{?}{=} Cov(X, Y)$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are scaled (i.e. divided by their respective standard deviation), will the $\beta_0$ (i.e. the intercept) be affected?

If $X$ and $Y$ are scaled (i.e. divided by their respective standard deviation), will the $\beta_1$ (i.e. the slope) be affected?


Thanks for your time.

May I ask the purpose of standardizing the data? A linear model should predict $Y^T$  from $X^T$ and I don't really see from the question why you would standardize?

Is this a homework question or some other exercise?
